# Why isn't a promise passed as prop caught despite call to .catch inside the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, es6-promise

Why isn't the promise caught despite the call to .catch in the Async component and having enough time to execute it (1000ms)

```js
// App.js
import { useEffect, useMemo, useState } from "react";

let delay = (handle, time) => new Promise((res, rej) => setTimeout(() => handle(res, rej), time));

function Async({ value, children }) {
  let [result, setResult] = useState(null);
  let [error, setError] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (value) value.then(setResult).catch(setError);
  }, [value]);

  return children(result, error);
}

export default function App() {
  let rejected = useMemo(() => delay((res, rej) => rej("Something went wrong..."), 1000), []);

  return <Async value={rejected}>{(result, error) => error}</Async>
}
```

```
// index.js
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

The message "Something went wrong..." is rendered but following error is thrown:

> Uncaught (in promise) Something went wrong...

If the promise is created inside the Async component then the error is caught. For that instead of passing the promise I'm passing a function that returns a promise

```js
function Async({ value, children }) {
  // ...
  useEffect(() => {
    value().then(setResult).catch(setError);
  }, [value]);
  // ...
}

export default function App() {
  let rejected = () => delay((res, rej) => rej("Something went wrong..."), 1000);

  return <Async value={rejected}>{(result, error) => error}</Async>
}
```

Comment: `useEffect in Async doesn't make much difference.`  It certainly will.

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: I guess ReactJS doesn't guarantee that every call to the `App` function will lead to (exactly) one rendering of the `Async` component. Also the `Async` component might be rendered more often than a new promise is passed to it - especially since it uses state, and unconditionally attaches promise handlers whenever the state changes, which might even lead to an infinite loop. You definitely should attach the promise handlers in an effect hook.

Comment: `useEffect` is meant exactly for that.

Comment: Now that you've added your `useEffect`, You will want to do a null check on your `return children(result, error);` otherwise it will just execute immediately.   eg.. `if (result || error) return children(result, error) else return null;` ..   The return null is there so that nothing is rendered until it's ready.

Comment: @Keith The problem is the uncaught error thrown by the rejected promise

Comment: @MateusSarmento Can you provide a [mcve] please? I don't get any unhandled rejection events from your code.

Comment: @Bergi You can see it here: https://codesandbox.io/s/bitter-darkness-782yv?file=/src/App.js See the actual error log in the browser inspector using this url https://782yv.csb.app codesandbox is not logging the error

Comment: @Bergi not sure if I saved the code in this new link by the time you open it but now it is

Comment: @MateusSarmento That example is running in strict mode with a development build, which [intentionally double-invokes the `App` rendering and also the `useMemo` callback](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html). So it creates two promises, only one of which will be passed to `Async`.

Comment: @Bergi I see it! Thanks by the way. But I've put some logs in the code and I don't see the App and useMemo being invoked more than once.

Comment: I'm not sure if react is messing with `console.log`, but if you place breakpoints in the debugger you can see it clearly.

Comment: Actually yes, it does exactly that. From the docs I linked: "*Note: Starting with React 17, React automatically modifies the console methods like console.log() to silence the logs in the second call to lifecycle functions*"

Comment: Nailed it! Turns out, in the second StrictMode invocation, useMemo is recreating the promise and useEffect is not being called which is quite strange since it has the promise as a dependency

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe it should be recalled like it is for useMemo.

Comment: @MateusSarmento The problem really is with creating a promise inside a `useMemo`. Creating a promise and starting the timeout is itself a side effect. The two promises returned are distinct entities, and React should complain about the `useMemo` callback not being pure - but probably it uses structural equality for that dev mode check. Using the function that returns a promise, and executing that from `useEffect`, is the proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not getting the uncaught error..

Are you using some Promise library, or a particular Browser that shows this error?.

eg..

```js
const {useEffect, useMemo, useState, StrictMode, useCallback} = React;

let delay = (handle, time) => new Promise((res, rej) => setTimeout(() => handle(res, rej), time));


function Async({ value, children }) {
  let [result, setResult] = useState(null);
  let [error, setError] = useState(null);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (value) value.then(setResult).catch(setError);
  }, [value]);

  return result || error ? children(result, error) : null;
}

function App() {
  let rejected = useMemo(() => delay((res, rej) => rej("Something went wrong..."), 1000), [null]);
  rejected.catch(() => {});
  return <Async value={rejected}>{(result, error) => error}</Async>
}

ReactDOM.render(<StrictMode><App/></StrictMode>, document.querySelector('#mount'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="mount"></div>
```

Comment: That looks like something with codesandbox, try running this snippet here..

Comment: Keith, it is: https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-star-wyklw?file=/src/App.js See the actual error log in the inspector using this url https://782yv.csb.app/ codesandbox is not logging the error

Comment: @MateusSarmento  Have you tried running the snippet here?, just click the `Run code snippet` button, it doesn't show the error, so there is something else going on here on that sandbox.  Debugging, it seems like the Promise is created twice in the sandbox, and that's why it's giving you the unhandled.  But why the sandbox is doing that, and this snippet doesn't not really sure.

Comment: @MateusSarmento  Ok, sussed it. Your Sandbox is using something called `StrictMode`, and that's causes App to render twice, that in turn is causing the Promise to be created twice..

Comment: Thanks mate. Removing the StrictMode solved the issue.

Comment: Ok looking at the Docs for `StrictMode` this double render is removed during production so normally wouldn't be an issue. I assume `StrictMode` is not meant to wrap the whole application, but parts of the application.  As a dirty hack I've put the `StrictMode` in above the above snippet, and if you do `rejected.catch(() => {});` to catch the dangling Promise it prevents the error.  But doing this doesn't feel right.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Root of the problem is the usage of StrictMode as pointed out by @Keith and @Bergi.
The StrictMode component causes a double-invocation of its children and the useMemo, useState and useReducer hooks. useEffect is not included.

The promise will be recreated by useMemo but won't be handled in useEffect since it isn't recalled even though it uses the promise as dependency.